# Neighing the active effect of Special Delivery in unstable unicorns

Tags: unstable-unicorns

So the neigh card states you can only neigh a card that is played, so the debate is does the active effect of "You may *bring* a baby unicorn card from the nursery into your stable" count as playing a card?

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not count as "playing" a card.
From the [rules](https://12ax7web.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/1/images/lot_23484_rules.pdf):

> **Play vs. Bring Directly into Your Stable**
>
> "Play" specifically refers to playing a card from your hand
> during your Action phase or playing an Instant card at any
> time. If you "bring a card directly into your Stable," you
> do not "play" that card. This means that any card that is
> brought directly into your Stable cannot be Neigh'd.

Note that there are two print runs, and the earlier version included a [different rulebook](https://12ax7web.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/1/images/Lot_23167_rules.pdf) without this clarification.